# ng-repeat con variable dinamica

Tags: html, angular

Tengo una aplicacion en angular donde necesito registrar N cajas y dentro de cada caja N documentos.
A traves de la directiva ng-repeat de angular y una funcion de javascript he logrado crear las N cajas, pero no asi con los documentos porque cuando creo el arreglo que contendra la informacion de los mismos, al tratar de agregar un nuevo documento dentro de una caja, se crea al mismo tiempo un nuevo dpocumento en las otras cajas.
Quiero saber como puedo manejar esto, he pensado en crear arreglos dinamicos que vanyan en el ng-repeat de los documentos pero no ha sido posible.
Alguna sugerencia?

Javascript

```js
class RequestAddController{
    constructor($stateParams,$state, API, $http,$filter){
        'ngInject';
        var vm = this
        this.API = API
        this.lines=[]
        this.clines=[]
        this.alerts = []
        this.description=[]
        this.cardboard_id=[]
        this.date_start=[]
        this.date_end=[]
        this.stay_time=[]

        let i= 0;
        this.lines = eval("this.lines"+i);
        this.lines = []
        this.lines.push({id : 0});

        this.clines.push({id : 0});
        this.$state= $state
        this.request_type = 2
        this.formSubmitted = false

        if ($stateParams.alerts) {
        this.alerts.push($stateParams.alerts)
        }

        let request= this.API.service('index', this.API.all('requests'))
        request.one().get().then((response)=>{
            let requestsResponse= response.plain()
            this.request =  requestsResponse.data.requests
                //console.log(requestsResponse.data.requests.length)
            if (this.request.length > 0){
                let long= this.request.length

                let date_today = new Date()
                let year = date_today.getFullYear()
                let month = date_today.getMonth()+1
                let day = date_today.getDate()
                this.id= this.request[long-1].id+1
                var date = day+"-"+month+"-"+year
                //console.log(year)
                
                this.request_number="C"+"-"+this.id+"-"+date
                //console.log("id",this.id) 

            }
            else{
              let long= this.request.length

                let date_today = new Date()
                let year = date_today.getFullYear()
                let month = date_today.getMonth()+1
                let day = date_today.getDate()
                var date = day+"-"+month+"-"+year
                this.id = 1
                //console.log("this.id",this.id)
                this.request_number = "C"+"-"+this.id+"-"+date
                //console.log("this.request_number", this.request_number)
            } 
            let date_today = new Date()
            let year = date_today.getFullYear()
            let month = date_today.getMonth()+1
            let day = date_today.getDate()
            date_today = year+"-"+month+"-"+day
            this.date_request = date_today
            console.log("fecha de hoy", this.date_request)
            console.log(requestsResponse.data)
        })

         this.systemApplicants ={}
         this.systemApplicants[0] = {id:1, name:'Solicitante 1' }
         this.systemApplicants[1]= {id:2 , name:'Solicitante 2'}  
         console.log("systemApplicants",this.systemApplicants)

         this.systemCardboards ={}
         this.systemCardboards[0] = {id:1, name: 'Caja 1' }
         this.systemCardboards[1]= {id:2 , name:'Caja 2'}  
         console.log("systemCardboards",this.systemCardboards)
         
        

    }
    addDoc() {
      if (this.lines.length==0){
          var newid = 0
      }
      else{
          var newid = this.lines.length
      }
      this.lines.push({id : newid});

          //console.log('lineas',this.lines)
      
      //console.log('archivos',this.files)
    }
    addCardboard() {
        if (this.clines.length==0){
            var newid = 0
        }
        else{
            var newid = this.clines.length
        }
        this.clines.push({id : newid});
        
        var i= newid;
        this.lines = eval("this.lines"+i);
        this.lines = []
        this.lines.push({id : 0});
        console.log("docs", this.cline)

            //console.log('lineas',this.lines)
        
        //console.log('archivos',this.files)
    }
      deleteCLine(index){//eliminar de los archivos nuevos agregados
        //console.log('antes')
        //console.log('lines',this.lines)
        //console.log('cardboard_id',this.cardboard_id)
        //console.log('value',this.value)
        //console.log('files',this.files)


        let pos = this.clines.indexOf(index);
        this.clines.splice(pos,1)
        //console.log('pos',pos)
        this.cardboard_id.splice(pos,1)
        this.value.splice(pos,1)
        this.file.splice(pos,1)

        for(var i=0; i<this.cardboard_id.length;i++) this.cardboard_id[i] = parseInt(this.cardboard_id[i], 10);

        let newcvalue = -1
        let neclines = []
        angular.forEach(this.clines, function (value) {
            neclines.push({id : newcvalue+1})
            newcvalue++
        })
        this.clines = neclines

        //console.log('despues')
        
        //console.log('cardboard_id',this.cardboard_id)
        //console.log('value',this.value)
        
    }
      deleteLine(index){//eliminar de los archivos nuevos agregados
        //console.log('antes')
        //console.log('lines',this.lines)
        //console.log('cardboard_id',this.cardboard_id)
        //console.log('value',this.value)
        //console.log('files',this.files)


        let pos = this.lines.indexOf(index);
        this.lines.splice(pos,1)
        //console.log('pos',pos)
        this.cardboard_id.splice(pos,1)
        this.value.splice(pos,1)
        this.file.splice(pos,1)

        for(var i=0; i<this.cardboard_id.length;i++) this.cardboard_id[i] = parseInt(this.cardboard_id[i], 10);

        let newvalue = -1
        let nelines = []
        angular.forEach(this.lines, function (value) {
            nelines.push({id : newvalue+1})
            newvalue++
        })
        this.lines = nelines

        //console.log('despues')
        
        //console.log('cardboard_id',this.cardboard_id)
        //console.log('value',this.value)
        
    }
    /*getDateRequest(dater){
    
        var date = new Date(dater)
        console.log('date_request', date)
        var day = dater.getDate();
        var month = dater.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = dater.getFullYear();
        var date_r = year + '-' + month + '-'+ day;
        this.date_request = date_r
        console.log("date_request",this.date_request) 
        //return this.date_request
    }
    getDateStart(dates){
    
      for (var i = 0; i < this.date_start.length; i++) {      
        var date = new Date(dates)
        console.log('date_start', date)
        var day = dates.getDate();
        var month = dates.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = dates.getFullYear();
        var date_s = year + '-' + month + '-'+ day;
        this.date_start[i] = date_s
        console.log("date_start",this.date_start[i]) 
        //return this.date_start
      }
    }

    getDateEnd(datee){
    
      for (var i = 0; i < this.date_end.length; i++) {    
        var date = new Date(datee)
        console.log('date_end', date)
        var day = datee.getDate();
        var month = datee.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = datee.getFullYear();
        var date_e = year + '-' + month + '-'+ day;
        this.date_end[i] = date_e
        console.log("date_end",this.date_end[i]) 
        //return this.date_end
      }
    }*/


    save (isValid) {
    //this.$state.go(this.$state.current, {}, { alerts: 'test' })
    if (isValid) {

      let requests= this.API.service('requests', this.API.all('requests'))
      let $state = this.$state
      
      console.log("date_start",this.date_start)
      console.log("date_end",this.date_end)
      const fd = new FormData()
      


      /*for (var i = 0; i < this.date_start.length; i++) {  
      
      var date_start = new Date(this.date_start[i]);
      var day = date_start.getDay();
      var month = date_start.getMonth() + 1;
      var year = date_start.getFullYear();
      var date_s = year + '-' + month + '-'+ day;
      this.date_start[i]= date_s
      console.log("date_start",this.date_start[i])
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < this.date_end.length; i++) {
    
      var date_end = new Date(this.date_end[i]);
      var day = date_end.getDay();
      var month = date_end.getMonth() + 1;
      var year = date_end.getFullYear();
      var date_e = year + '-' + month + '-'+ day;
      this.date_end[i]= date_e

      console.log("date_end",this.date_end[i])
      }*/
 
      
      fd.append('request_type', this.request_type)
      fd.append('request_id', this.id)
      fd.append('request_number', this.request_number)
      fd.append('applicant_id', this.systemApplicants[0].id)
      fd.append('date_request', this.date_request)
      fd.append('cardboard_id', JSON.stringify(this.cardboard_id))
      fd.append('description', JSON.stringify(this.description))
      fd.append('date_start', JSON.stringify(this.date_start))
      fd.append('date_end', JSON.stringify(this.date_end))
      fd.append('observation', this.observation)
      fd.append('stay_time', JSON.stringify(this.stay_time))

      requests.post(fd).then(function() {
          let alert = { type: 'success', 'title': 'Exito!', msg: 'La solicitud ha sido creada.' }
          $state.go($state.current, { alerts: alert})
        }, (response) => {
          let alert = { type: 'error', 'title': 'Error!', msg: response.data.message }
          $state.go($state.current, { alerts: alert})
        })
    } else {
      this.formSubmitted = true
    }
}

    $onInit(){
    }
}

export const RequestAddComponent = {
    templateUrl: './views/app/components/request-add/request-add.component.html',
    controller: RequestAddController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindings: {}
}
/*import Controller from '../../../classes/save.controller'

/**
 * Agrega una nueva bodega al sistema.
 */
/*class CustodyCardboardRequestAddController extends Controller {
  /**
   * Método ejecutado al inicializar el controlador.
   * Establece las configuraciones de la ruta actual.
   */
  /*boot() {
    this.route = 'custody_cardboard_requests'
    this.states = 'custody_cardboard_request'
    this.title = 'Solicitud de custodia de documentos en archivo general'
    this.breadcrumbs = [
      {name: 'Inicio', state:this.baseState, icon: 'fa fa-tachometer-alt'},
      {name: 'Solicitud', state: this.listsState, icon: 'fa fa-archive'},
      {name: 'Nueva', active: true}
    ]
  }
}
export const CustodyCardboardRequestAddComponent = {
    templateUrl: './views/app/components/custody_cardboard_request-add/custody_cardboard_request-add.component.html',
    controller: CustodyCardboardRequestAddController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindings: {}
}*/


HTML
```

```html
<section class="content-header">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title" >Solicitud de custodia de documentos en archivo general</h3>
  </div>
</section>
<br/>
<section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h1 class="box-title">Datos Básicos </small></h1>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="Form" ng-submit="vm.save(Form.$valid)" novalidate>
          <div class="box-body">
            <div ng-if="vm.alerts" class="alert alert-{{alert.type}}" ng-repeat="alert in vm.alerts">
              <h4>{{alert.title}}</h4>
              <p>{{alert.msg}}</p>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="request_number" class="control-label"></i> Nro. Solicitud</label>
                <input type="text"style="width: 140px" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.request_number" name="request_number" disabled="true">
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <h4 class="box-title">Detalles</h4>-->
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td><label for="applicant" class="control-label col-md-1">Solicitante</label></td>
                <!--<td style="padding-left: 20px"><label for="date_request" class="control-label col-md-1">Fecha</label></td> --> 
                <td style="padding-left: 20px"><label for="observation" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Observaciones</label></td>
              </tr>  
              <tr>
                <td>  
                  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': Form.applicant.$invalid && ( vm.formSubmitted || Form.applicant.$touched) }">          
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                      <input type="text" style="width: 150px" class="form-control" name="applicant_id" ng-model="vm.systemApplicants[0].name" value="vm.systemApplicants[0].id" disabled="true"> 
                        <!--<select class="form-control" style="width: 250px"  ng-model="vm.applicant_id" disabled="true" name="applicant">
                          <option value="1">Seleccione</option>-->
                          <!--<option ng-repeat="item in vm.systemApplicants" ng-value="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
                        </select>-->
                        <p ng-show="Form.applicant.$error.required && ( vm.formSubmitted || Form.applicant.$touched)" class="help-block">Seleccione un aprovador.</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </td>
              <!--<td >
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (form.date_request.$invalid && ( vm.formSubmitted || form.date_request.$touched)) || vm.hasErrors('date_request') }">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">  
                      <input type="date" class="form-control" style='font-size: 14px; width: 150px;margin-left:20px' ng-model="vm.date_request" name="date_request" ng-focus="vm.cleanErrors('date_request')" ng-change="vm.getDateRequest(vm.date_request)" required>
                      <p ng-show="form.date_request.$error.required && ( vm.formSubmitted || form.date_request.$touched)" class="help-block">Requerido.</p>
                      <p ng-show="vm.hasErrors('date_request')" class="help-block">{{ vm.getError('date_request') }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </td>-->
              <td > 
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (Form.observation.$invalid && ( vm.formSubmitted || Form.observation.$touched)) || vm.hasErrors('observation') }">
                  
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <textarea class="form-control" style="width: 300px;margin-left:20px;margin-top: 20px" ng-model="vm.observation" name="observation" ng-focus="vm.cleanErrors('observation')"></textarea>
                    <p ng-show="vm.hasErrors('observation')" class="help-block">{{ vm.getError('observation') }}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </table>
            <hr/>
            
              <h4 class="box-title">Cajas</h4>
              <div ng-repeat="cline in vm.clines">

                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': Form.cardboard_id{{cline.id}}.$invalid && ( vm.formSubmitted || Form.cardboard_id{{cline.id}}.$touched) }">
                  <label for="cardboard_id{{cline.id}}" class="control-label col-sm-1">Nro.Caja</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">    
                    <select  style="width: 140px"  class="form-control"  ng-model="vm.cardboard_id[cline.id]" name="cardboard_id{{cline.id}}" required>
                      <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                      <option value="6">6</option>
                      <option value="7">7</option>
                      <option value="8">8</option>
                      <option value="9">9</option>
                      <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                    <p ng-show="Form.cardboard_id{{cline.id}}.$error.required && ( vm.formSubmitted || Form.cardboard_id{{cline.id}}.$touched)" class="help-block">Seleccione una caja.</p>
                  </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="box-header with-border"  align="right">                   
                  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="vm.addCardboard();">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"  ng-show="vm.clines.length > 1" ng-click="vm.deleteCLine(cline);" >
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
                              
                <div  ng-repeat="line in vm.lines" >
                  <fieldset>
                    <table>
                      <tr>      
                        <td ><label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripción</label></td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 20px"><label for="date_start" class="control-label">Fecha Inicio</label></td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 40px"><label for="date_end" class="control-label">Fecha Fin</label></td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 40px"><label for="stay_time" class="control-label">Tiempo de permanencia</label></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <!-- Description -->
                          <div class="form-group" style="width:350px" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (Form.description{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}.$invalid && ( vm.formSubmitted || Form.description{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}.$touched)) || vm.hasErrors('description{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}') }">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">                        
                              
                              <textarea class="form-control" style="width: 300px;margin-top: 20px;margin-right: 200px; " ng-model="vm.description[cline.id][line.id]" name="description{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}" ng-focus="vm.cleanErrors('description{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}')" required></textarea>
                              <p ng-show="vm.hasErrors('description{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}')" class="help-block">{{ vm.getError('description') }}</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td> 
                          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (Form.date_start{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}.$invalid && ( vm.formSubmitted || Form.date_start{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}.$touched)) || vm.hasErrors('date_start{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}') }">
                              <div class="col-sm-8">
                                
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" style='font-size: 14px; width: 150px;' ng-model="vm.date_start[cline.id][line.id]" name="date_start{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}" ng-change="vm.getDateStart(vm.date_start{{cline.id}}{{line.id}})"  ng-focus="vm.cleanErrors('date_start')" required>
                                <p ng-show="form.date_start{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}.$error.required && ( vm.formSubmitted || form.date_start{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}.$touched)" class="help-block">Requerido.</p>
                                <p ng-show="vm.hasErrors('date_start{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}')" class="help-block">{{ vm.getError('date_start') }}</p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <div  style="width:200px"class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (Form.date_end{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}.$invalid && ( vm.formSubmitted || Form.date_end{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}.$touched)) || vm.hasErrors('date_end{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}') }">
                              <div class="col-sm-8">  
                                
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" style='font-size: 14px; width: 150px;margin-left:20px' ng-model="vm.date_end[cline.id][line.id]" name="date_end{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}" ng-change="vm.getDateEnd(vm.date_end{{cline.id}}{{line.id}})" ng-focus="vm.cleanErrors('date_end')"  min="{{vm.date_start[cline.id][line.id] | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" required>
                                <p ng-show="form.date_end{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}.$error.required && ( vm.formSubmitted || form.date_end{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}.$touched)" class="help-block">Requerido.</p>
                                <p ng-show="vm.hasErrors('date_end{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}')" class="help-block">{{ vm.getError('date_end') }}</p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (Form.stay_time{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}.$invalid && ( vm.formSubmitted || Form.stay_time{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}.$touched)) || vm.hasErrors('stay_time') }">
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                              <select  style="width: 140px;margin-left:40px" class="form-control" name="stay_time{{cline.id}}{{line.id}}" ng-model="vm.stay_time[cline.id][line.id]" required>
                                <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                              </select>
                              <p ng-show="vm.hasErrors('stay_time')" class="help-block">{{ vm.getError('stay_time') }}</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      <td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  </div>   
                  <div class="box-header with-border" align="right">                   
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="vm.addDoc()">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-show=" vm.lines.length > 1 " ng-click="vm.deleteLine(line)" >
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    </a>
                  </div>  
                </fieldset>
              </div>
            <div class="box-footer">
            <a ui-sref="app.request-lists" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Regresar</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Guardar</button>
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Creo que no esta muy claro lo que quiero hacer...voy a colocar un ejemplo...imaginen que van al supermercado y agarras una bolsa y la llenas de un kilo de pasta, arroz, leche...luego agarras otra bolsa y la llenas con tomates y papas...luego tomas otra bolsa y la llenas con azucar, cafe y huevos.